# I want to select individual visibility keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

When I insert keyframe of visibility or camera it applies keyframe to other objects as well as if they are part of the group. And from that I can't individual modify on what frames these individual objects would be visible as it affects the others who are part of the group.

Any Solutions Please?

Here are the details:
[image]

I did this by just pressing I and suddenly 2 other objects were included

Comment: Welcome to bse. Can you please provide more detail on how you are inserting such keyframes.

Comment: Highlight the individual object you wish to modify 1st to the left. Your outliner shows cube as the selected object. Other than that should be fine regardless of whether the objects are part of a group or not. if you still have difficulties the python command should be similar to below.  bpy.context.object["obj_name"].keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render", frame=my_frame)

Comment: Interesting, can't replcate this behaviour. (blender 2.79.3) Does it also do this with the outliner in current scene display mode?  Could be one for the [bug tracker](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/2217)